# matplotlib add to panedwindow in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I do not understand how correctly add matplotlib into panedwindow of tkinter.
I want to have on one side list box and matplotlib interactive plot, on the other side
I need to resize listbox and plot by dragging boundary between them

[this is what is desirable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ314.png)

I tried this but I cannot add correctly matplot lib to paned window

```
from tkinter import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

root = Tk()

m = PanedWindow(root)
m.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)




fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
m.add(toolbar)
m.add(canvas)



lstbox2 = Listbox(selectmode=MULTIPLE, width=20, height=10)
m.add(lstbox2) 

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `canvas` and `toolbar` in a `Frame` instead, and add that `Frame` to your paned window:

```
root = Tk()

...

canvas_frame = Frame(root)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = canvas_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, canvas_frame)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.pack_configure(expand=True)

m.add(canvas_frame)

lstbox2 = Listbox(selectmode=MULTIPLE, width=20, height=10)
m.add(lstbox2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I’ll check it out.